# BoundingBox key in Geo API of Redis

Tags: osm2pgsql, cache, extents

I am very happy so see that [Redis](http://redis.io) now offers a [Geo API](http://redis.io/commands#geo)

I would like to host a service where, given a latitude-longitude pair, 
I retrieve a bounding-box (of OSM) from a pgsql query. 
Since I expect queries to be done in the proximity of each other, I would like to cache the bounding-boxes.

Then, given a new latitude-longitude pair, I would like to use redis to see if the query coordinates fall into a bounding-box recently queried.

Does anybody know if the Geo API of Redis supports bounding boxes. 
Or maybe there is a different approach to make above task more efficient.

Comment: GeoHash might be the closest you can get.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have to work with radius/ distance, not bounding boxes.
You can check if a previous point falls within a given distance to the new point using [GEODIST](http://redis.io/commands/geodist) or store all previous points and use the [GEORADIUS](http://redis.io/commands/georadius) to find all points within a given distance.